# How to identify the relavent products whn calculating precision@k for top -n recommendations

Tags: metrics

I have developed a basic user-based collaborative filtering model. I need to evaluate the effectiveness of this model by measuring the quality of the top n recommendations it produces. I have come across the term 'precision@k,' which is a metric used to calculate the number of relevant items in the top n recommendations. However, I am unclear about how to define a 'relevant item.' Can I base it on a ratings threshold, such as only selecting items rated higher than 3 (for example, in the MovieLens dataset)?

In this case I also dont understand why we need to divide the data into a train and test split, because according to my knowledge my final top n recommendation will be produced by considering all the datase, so why split the data while evaluating these metric.

My other question is when doing a complementary recommendation service using co occurrences, what metric or any other method we can use to evaluate the performance of my top n reccomendaitons.